# Is there a way with JMeter to define: numberOfThreadsPerMinute, threadIncreaseTimeUnit and threadIncreaseNumberPerTimeUnit

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I have a case with JMeter were I need to define three conditions to a load-test. Plase give some detailed info, because I have not to much experience with JMeter.

1. `numberOfThreadsPerMinute`: How many threads to run in a minute
2. `threadIncreaseTimeUnit`: Time period before increase the number of threads per minute
3. `threadIncreaseNumberPerTimeUnit`: The number of threads per minute to be increased (added to `numberOfThreadsPerMinute`) after `threadIncreaseTimeUnit` minutes.

What the Testplan does is to call some Java-code that calls then a PDF converter Server over JMS.
I tried with a Thread-Group element, but there are not all the options I need. I think I have to add some other elements (like a Timer or Loop) but I am not sure which and how.

My Testplan looks like that:

```
       |-Thread-Group
         |-User Defined Variables
         |-Simple Controller
         | |
         | |-JSR223 Sampler (PDF to PNG) -script to call Java-classes
         | |-JSR223 Sampler (TIFF to PNG)
         |-Simple Controller
         | |-JSR223 Sampler (PDF to TIFF)
         |-Simple Controller
         | |-JSR223 Sampler (Merge PNGs)
```

Can you please tell me how can I achive the above requirements?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below thread groups plugin for your requirement:-

[ThroughputShapingTimer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/)

[UltimateThreadGroup](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/)

Hope this helps.